# How to Impersonate WCF Client executed inside WorkflowApplication?

Tags: wcf, workflow

I have the following scenario:

I have workflow application object running a workflow activity. In the workflow activity logic, I call a WCF service in which the service operations is also generated as a set activities.

The problem is: How can I pass the credentials and impersonate other user in this case as its regularly done like this:

```
MyServiceClient client = new MyServiceClient();
client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Domain = domain;
client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName = username;
client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Password = password;
```

I tried to impersonate the code block that runs the the workflow application object, but in that case, I get some kind of exception saying "Could not load file or assembly ....  Access is denied". As I understand, the reason of this exception is that the workflow application is trying to call assembly which is under the original logged on user.

Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

Windows authentication using the calling process's credentials is the best supported authentication method, but there are activities for handling username/password authentication in the WF Security Pack CTP 1 on the WF CodePlex site (https://wf.codeplex.com/releases/view/48114). See `TokenFlowScope` and `GetUserNameSecurityToken`. This article goes through it in detail: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598919.aspx. I haven't tried this, and would avoid it if at all possible.

For your second problem, there's a bit more to making workflows running under WorkflowApplication impersonate. From the same article:

> The security context of a calling thread isn’t copied to the workflow thread, so even if the workflow client is impersonating, the WF thread—which is executing the activities—won’t be impersonating. The security context of the caller can be flown to the WF thread using a custom Synchronization context that would forward the call on the same incoming Async thread, similar to the Synchronization context used by the WorkflowInvoker

```
public class MySyncContext : SynchronizationContext
{
  public override void Post(SendOrPostCallback d, object state)
  {
    d(state);
  }
}
```